# css applying width on the body

Tags: css

I am completely new to html and css so my question could be very basic but hope you guys can help me udnerstnad,

I am using following css code

```
    body
    {
        background-color:Olive;
        width:550px;           
        font-family:Verdana;
    }
```

I am setting width to 550px and as a result all my paragraphs contract to 550px but the background is applied to the whole page even beyond the 550px

I understand that because of inheritance the child elements would have inherited the width property from body, but I was thinking that if I set width property of body to 550px then background should be visible in 550px wide area and not the full page,

I don't get the logic here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply a color to the html, for example `html { background-color: yellow; }`, you'll see this is not the case at all. The `<body>` tag is special in that it is intended to encompass the entire contents of the HTML page. When you apply a background, then, the default is for it to paint the entire background page, unless `html`s background has otherwise been set.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JgZcK/) example. Like the other posters above, I highly recommend using a `<div>` element to wrap, size, and color your content.

This is described in the [CSS2 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html) as so:

> The background of the root element becomes the background of the canvas and covers the entire canvas, anchored (for 'background-position') at the same point as it would be if it was painted only for the root element itself. The root element does not paint this background again.

Comment: Is there any documentation on how background-color behaves in body tag and in rest of the html elements?

Comment: @kiranvj - See the [CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html). I'm sure there's an equivalent section/discussion in the CSS3 spec as well. Specifically: "The background of the root element becomes the background of the canvas and covers the entire canvas, anchored (for 'background-position') at the same point as it would be if it was painted only for the root element itself. The root element does not paint this background again."

Comment: Updated answer to include CSS2 spec info.

Answer (score 1):

Why not wrap your content in a div, and set the properties to that?

```
<body>
<div class="content">
 ... content here
</div>
</body>
```

and apply the same classes to the div

```
.content
    {
        background-color:Olive;
        width:550px;           
        font-family:Verdana;
    }
```

Comment: @Mike thanks it worked but can I ask why appplying width directly to body does not work ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use a container `div` that wraps your whole page and acts like a "fake" `body`. Then if you apply these style to this `div` your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

**css**

```
#wrapper {
    width: 550px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        Piece of text inside a 550px width div centered on the page
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this http://jsfiddle.net/ajaypatel_aj/8tfKc/
HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">Test me!</div>​
```

CSS

```
*{  
   margin:0;  
   padding:0;  
}  

body{  
   text-align:center; /*For IE6 Shenanigans*/  
    font-family:Verdana;
}  

#wrapper{  
   width:550px;  
   margin:0 auto;  
   text-align:left;  
    background-color:Olive;
} 
​
```

Answer is simple applied body color will set to whole page you must have to use div .

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Your title goes here.
        </title>
    </head>
<style type="text/css">
#test
{
    background-color:Olive;
    width:550px;           
    font-family:Verdana;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div id='test'>
    Hello
    </div>
</body>
```

Another answer is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Your title goes here.
    </title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    html
    {
        background-color:white;
    }
    body
    {
        background-color:Olive;
        width:550px;
        font-family:Verdana;
    }
</style>
<body>
    Hello
</body>
</html>
```