# why does header and content fall short of body width

Tags: html, css

I am having a weird situation with the code below, my `body` width is set to `980px` and my header and content width is set to `100%` so they should stretch throughout screen but in firefox they fall short by few pixels and in chrome they just reach the half way, the weird thing is body of page is covering whole screen I checked it by setting `background:black` for `body` and whole page turned black then how header and content can fall short with `width:100%` .But this code works fine on cssdesk [cssdesk](http://cssdeck.com/labs/4ohlx5b8) so what is wrong with my browsers. My screen resolution is 1366x768.

```css
body {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000;
}
.header {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #F23F21;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
}
.one {
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.two {
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
}
.three {
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid green;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">This is header</div>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="one">
    </div>
    <div class="two">
    </div>
    <div class="three">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The body is not stretching to fill the screen. There are just special rules for how the background colour is handled on the body element (it is used to colour the viewport itself).

The body is the width you gave it. That width is narrower than your browser window.

Everything else is constrained within it.

Comment: This, see discussion here for body size/color: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721574/css-applying-width-on-the-body

Comment: thanks but can you explain what people mean of 980px as best choice for page width, are they talking about setting width of content rather that body?

Comment: They are talking about the width of the content.

Answer (score 1):

Dont fix width of your body, inside body create a container div

i have modified your code check this

```html
<style>
    body{}
    .container{
    width:980px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000;
}
.header{
  color:#fff;
  margin: 0;
 width:100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color:#F23F21;
}
#container{
    width:100%;
}
.one{
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.two{
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:50%;
}
.three{
    height:200px;
    float:right;
    border:1px solid green;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:25%;
}

</style>
<body>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="header">This is header</div> 
<div id="container">
<div class="one">
</div>
<div class="two">
</div>
<div class="three"> 
</div>
</div>
  </div>
</body>
```